# Doing Some Minor For Each in Linq

Tags: linq

I have a minor problem guys which I need some help. I have a Restaurant object which has the fields : districtId, dishId, foodCategoryId and restaurantName.

Based on my code below, I need to check from the districtId array input parameter if it has a match in the RestaurantTable. I have an idea I should use

```
 districtId.ToList().Foreach( blah blah action )
```

but I am having a difficulty using it. Please advise. Thanks In advance.

My code snippet:

```
public IEnumerable<Restaurant> GetAllRestaurants(string restaurantName
        , int[] districtId
        , int dishId = 0
        , int foodCategoryId = 0)
    {

var q = RestaurantTable.Where(restaurants => restaurants.RestaurantName.Contains(restaurantName.ToLower().Trim())
                                                | restaurants.DishId == dishId
                                                | restaurants.FoodCategoryId == foodCategoryId
| "For each Id's in districtId check if it has a match in restaurants.DistrictId")

return q.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Contains()`:

```
    var q = RestaurantTable.Where(restaurant => restaurant.RestaurantName.Contains(restaurantName.ToLower().Trim())
                                 || restaurant.DishId == dishId
                                 || restaurant.FoodCategoryId == foodCategoryId
                                 || districtId.Contains(restaurant.DistrictId))
```

Also you want to use `||` (logical OR) instead of `|` (binary OR)

Comment: thanks for the answer, let me try that one. if you may, can you explain that part? Or am I correct, if districtId contains any of the restaurant.DistrictId, it will return true?